# Accessing a general use class from all over project

Tags: c++

In our application there is general used classes( e.g a class which holds project configuration parameters ) like below .

```
class DB{   
public:
int projectVersion
int somethingSoMuchImportantAllOverTheProject
};
extern DB* pDB;
```

Because all other classes will use this class, all of them needs to access it somehow . Our solution is putting "extern DB* pDB;" under its header file so whoever needs it, will be able to access it after including the header . I am thinking maybe there is a better solution and want to get your ideas for this general case.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a pointer?

Comment: I removed the 'c' tag, this is clearly C++.

Comment: What you are talking about is a simple global variable (in one form on another). So, to suggest a better option, need to see the whole picture as it's a design consideration, not just syntax.

Comment: Google for "singleton pattern," but be careful: there are issues with this (DLLs having their own instances etc.)

Comment: No it does not have to be a pointer . What matters for me is writing less code(like not passing the object to everyclass) and readability.Singleton pattern will be good improvement but I am also asking also about how link this object to other classes better.

Comment: Also, does it have to be an object?  If the only values it holds are constant primitives then it might be easier to just use namespaced static constants.

Comment: Yes it has to be a object because in our project thing are a little more complex than the example above. Also it is just for configuration class many other classes in our project like this case. They are big singletons and being used by other clases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a singleton.  You can find lots of discussions on it, but one important thing is, hide the constructor of the class so users of the class are forced to use the one object.

Comment: Singleton pattern will be good improvement but I am also asking also about how link this object to other classes better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "link" it... I assume you don't mean the link part of the build process.  Just "use" it directly in your code, e.g. check version via `pDB->projectVersion`.

Comment: I mentioned this becuase as I know singleton is about making the object single by means only allowing one instance of it . But what I am not sure putting object pointer to header like "extern DB* pDB;" in the example.

Comment: If you do a proper singleton, you don't put the pointer in directly.  For example, put the single object as a static private member of the class, then do `DB::getInstance()->projectVersion` instead of having that `extern` in the header (and thus everywhere).